# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getUsername() on null in con PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy tratando de hacer un login con PHP y PDO pero bueno despues de una serie de errores que he logrado solucionar y salir adelante sobre la marcha me topé con éste erorr y he estado indagando en foros pero no he logrado conseguir algo directamente relacionado a mi problema, adjunto una imagen del error en consola y con el respectivo código fuente
[image: Imagen del error en consola]

```
<?php
include 'UsuarioControlador.php';
include_once 'helps.php';

session_start();


header('Content-type: application/json');
$resultado = array();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(isset($_POST["usuario"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){

        $usuario = validar_campo($_POST["usuario"]);
        $password = validar_campo($_POST["password"]);
        
        $resultado = array("estado"=>"true");
        
        if(UsuarioControlador::login($usuario, $password)){
            
            $user = UsuarioControlador::getUsername($usuario, $password);
            $_SESSION["usuario"] = array (
            "nombre"=>$user->getUsername(),
            "password"=>$user->getPw(),
            );
            
        }
    
        }
}

$resultado = array("estado"=>"false");
return print(json_encode($resultado));


?>`

también adjuntaré lo que tengo en Usuario controlador.php

    <?php
include_once 'UsuarioDao.php';

class UsuarioControlador
{
    public static function login($usuario,$pw)
    {
      
     $obj_usuario = new Usuario();
     $obj_usuario->setUsername($usuario);
     $obj_usuario->setPw($pw);

     return UsuarioDao::login($obj_usuario);
 
    }

    public  function getUsername($usuario, $pw){
     $obj_usuario = new Usuario();
     $obj_usuario->setUsername($usuario);
     $obj_usuario->setPw($pw);
    }

}
?>


y por último lo que tengo en usuario dao 
`<?php 

require_once 'conexion.php';
require_once 'usuario.php';



class UsuarioDao extends Conexion
{
   protected static $cnx;

   private static function getConexion(){
       self::$cnx = conexion::conectar();

   }
   private static function desconectar()
   {
       self::$cnx = null;
   }


   public static function login($usuario)
   {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM registro WHERE  username = :usuario and pw = :password ";
   
     self::getConexion();
     $resultado = self::$cnx->prepare($query);
     $resultado->bindValue(":usuario", $usuario->getUsername());
     $resultado->bindValue(":password", $usuario->getPw());

    $resultado->execute();

    if($resultado->rowCount() > 0){
         $filas = $resultado->fetch();
         if ($filas["username"]==$usuario->getUsername()
         && $filas["pw"]==$usuario->getPW()){
           return true;
         }
     }{
     return false;
    }

}
//meotdo que sirve para obntener un usuario



public static function getUsername($usuario)
   {
     $query = "SELECT username, pw FROM registro WHERE  username = :usuario and pw = :password ";
   
     self::getConexion();
     $resultado = self::$cnx->prepare($query);
     $resultado->bindValue(":usuario", $usuario->getUsername());
     $resultado->bindValue(":password", $usuario->getPw());

    $resultado->execute();

    $filas = $resultado->fetch();

     $usuario = new Usuario();
     $usuario->setUsername($filas["username"]);
     $usuario->setpw($filas["pw"]);

     return $usuario;
    }

}

?>
```

Espero encontrar una solución en conjunto con la ayuda que me puedan brindar, y cualquier error o incongruencia en código pido disculpa de antemano, destaco que estoy comenzando en este hermoso mundo y pues nada aún me queda mucho por aprender

Comment: Tienes muchos errores en ese código. Para empezar, intentas acceder a un método no-estático desde una clase no instanciada y como si estuviera definido como estático: `$user = UsuarioControlador::getUsername($usuario, $password);`  Dentro de la clase creas un nuevo usuario con `new Usuario()` y, tal vez, debería ser `new UsuarioDao()`. En ambas clases falta un constructor para instanciar antes de acceder a cualquier otro método.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiar:

```
public function getUsername($usuario, $pw)
```

por:

```
public static function getUsername($usuario, $pw)
```

Esto porque estás llamando a la función `getUsername()` sin ningún objeto. La manera en la que se llaman a esa clase de funciones es desde un objeto de esa clase de la forma `$object->getUsername($params)` y en tu ejemplo no llamas a la función desde un objeto, si no que lo llamas de manera estática. Es por eso que, cuando tratas de llamarla te dice que `Call on null`, porque quiere trabajar a partir de un objeto que no existe

Comment: Convendría la explicaras por que debe pasar de un método no estático a uno estático